# Do we already have a list of problems that are almost like this one?(how many words can we make with the letters of BANANA)

Tags: discussion

over the years we have received a ton of questions similar to this one:

[How many words can be formed using all the letters of "DAUGHTER" so that vowels always come together?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1369974/how-many-words-can-be-formed-using-all-the-letters-of-daughter-so-that-vowels)

They are all basically the same, they have a restriction that can be solved via some kind of casework.

Has such a list for this been made before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This is a pretty good collection](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+letters+mississippi), and  then [there are more](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+permutations+letters+word).

I think search is preferable to a list, as far as duplicates are concerned, because the extra restrictions vary: it can be something about containing or not containing a string, or ending/beginning, or not having vowels together, or length restrictions, etc. It's easier to add a relevant keyword to one of the above searches than browse a long list looking for similar restrictions.